# How to download a file from json api backend using vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a rails api backend with vue.js frontend with simple jwt authentication.

So, there're 2 servers `localhost:8080` and `3000`

How can I download a pdf file from a link that goes with json response.

```
{
  "id": 25,
  "title": "test",
  "export_pdf": "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/export/25.pdf",
}
```

with the following code, I get `unauthorized` error because there's no localstorage on `localhost:3000`

```
<li><a :href="project.export_pdf" download='report'>Export as PDF</a></li>
```

-

I'm also using axios

and if I do something like this

```
  exportPdf: (url) => {
    return axios.get(url, auth.getHeader())
  }
```

it'll return the following

```
Object {data: "gibberish text", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: Object, config: Object…}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `responseType` for a `blob`, so `axios` you properly parse the data. Your back-end must return the header `content-disposition: attachment` in this file.

Also, I don't think you will be able to download it via Ajax. I can't understand your justification for an anchor, what LocalStorage change there?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

```
<a href="project.export_pdf" target="_blank">Export to PDF</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add download token at the end of a download link.

So, now I can do the following

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/projects/28/export?tkn=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
```

and then, on my frontend

```
<li><a :href="dllink" download='report.pdf'>Export as PDF</a></li>
```

-

```
dllink () {
 let tkn = window.localStorage.getItem('tkn')
 return `${this.project.export_pdf}?tkn=${tkn}`
}
```